# React data router - show fallback for loader

Tags: react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v 6.4 with `createBrowserRouter` to support the new data API.

I have routes that have a `loader`, and this loader can take 1-2 sec to get the data from the server, and I want to show a loading animation at that time.

See the following as a simple example of what I have, and a comment pointing to what I was expecting to do/find in the docs:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout/>,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Screen title="Home"/>,
      },
      {
        path: 'materials',
        loader: async () => {
          return (await fetch('/api/materials')).json()
        },
        fallbackElement: <Loading />, // <<--- THIS IS WHAT I WAS EXPECTING TO DO
        element: <Materials/>,
      },
      {
        path: 'projects',
        loader: async () => {
          return (await fetch('/api/projects')).json()
        },
        element: <Projects/>,
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

Could not find how to place a "fallback" element on a route to show while the loader is waiting for the data, only to place a `fallbackElement` on the `RouterProvider` component, but that is not what I want (it shows the fallback element only on the mount of `RouterProvider`, not when changing between routes).

Seems kinda weird that such a thing is not supported, and cannot really find answers through the search here as well.

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Deferred Data](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred) can achieve what you want.

1. return `defer({ expensiveData: promise })` in the loader
2. use `const data = useLoaderData()` in the component to get the data
3. use the below code

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
  <Await resolve={data.expensiveData}>
    {(expensiveData) => what you want to render}
  </Await>
</Suspense>
```

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation, on the component consuming the loader data you have to use React.Suspense and Await components to show the fallback, something like this:

```
import { Await, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";

function Book() {
  const { book, reviews } = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{book.title}</h1>
      <p>{book.description}</p>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<ReviewsSkeleton />}>
        <Await
          resolve={reviews}
          errorElement={
            <div>Could not load reviews </div>
          }
          children={(resolvedReviews) => (
            <Reviews items={resolvedReviews} />
          )}
        />
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/await#await

That's in theory, because I've done that and my loaders are not showing either.

Comment: `React.Suspense` is currently not available in user-code without special hacks and workarounds: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Suspense